# Help to solve four Simultaneous Equations with 4 unknowns

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve these simultaneous equations to get the values of a, b, c, and d.

```
y == a x (x + 1) Exp[b (1 - x/85)^(1/2)] + c x^2 + d x
```

for x and y values 
x={16,18,20,22}, and  y={337,377,416,454}

I used the following command

```
Solve[{337 == 256 c + 16 d + 272 a E^(Sqrt[69/85] b), 
  377 == 324 c + 18 d + 342 a E^(Sqrt[67/85] b), 
  416 == 400  c + 20 d + 420 a E^(Sqrt[13/17] b), 
  454 == 484 c + 22 d + 506 a E^(3 Sqrt[7/85] b)}, {a, b, c, d}]
```

But didn't get the desirable solving

Comment: Does `NonlinearModelFit` give acceptable results?

Comment: Looks like you need to use `FindRoot` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = Thread[
   y == a x (x + 1) Exp[b (1 - x/85)^(1/2)] + c x^2 + 
      d x /.
    {x -> {16, 18, 20, 22}, y -> {337, 377, 416, 454}}];
```

The exact solutions include [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects

```
sol = Solve[eqns, {a, b, c, d}, Reals] // Simplify
```

[image]

The approximate numeric solutions are

```
soln = sol // N

(* {{a -> 9.74433*10^-6, b -> 10.5665, c -> -0.0281118, 
  d -> 19.2541}, {a -> -5.95966*10^-18, b -> 39.3615, c -> -0.101709, 
  d -> 22.9454}} *)
```

Verifying the solutions

```
eqns /. sol // FullSimplify

(* {{True, True, True, True}, {True, True, True, True}} *)

eqns /. soln

(* {{True, True, True, True}, {True, True, True, True}} *)

Plot[Evaluate[
  a x (x + 1) Exp[b (1 - x/85)^(1/2)] + c x^2 + d x /.
   soln], {x, 
  15, 25},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
 PlotRange -> {300, 500},
 AxesLabel -> {x, y},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[Transpose[
     {{16, 18, 20, 22}, {337, 377, 416, 454}}]]},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {0.7, 0.3}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems there is no solutions to this system. One can see the system is linear in `{a, c, d}`, so it is convenient to eliminate them:

```
beq = Eliminate[{337 == 256 c + 16 d + 272 a E^(Sqrt[69/85] b), 
   377 == 324 c + 18 d + 342 a E^(Sqrt[67/85] b), 
   416 == 400 c + 20 d + 420 a E^(Sqrt[13/17] b), 
   454 == 484 c + 22 d + 506 a E^(3 Sqrt[7/85] b)}, {a, c, d}]
```

And we get single equation on `b`:

> `253 E^(3 Sqrt[7/85] b) + 513 E^(Sqrt[67/85] b) - 
>     136 E^(Sqrt[69/85] b) == 630 E^(Sqrt[13/17] b)`

`Solve, NSolve` and friends can not find solution, so we can investigate this with plotting:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Subtract @@ beq], {b, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

I tried more wide intervals for `b`, but the only solution is `b = 0`. But substitution this in original system gives no solution:

```
Solve[{337 == 256 c + 16 d + 272 a E^(Sqrt[69/85] b), 
   377 == 324 c + 18 d + 342 a E^(Sqrt[67/85] b), 
   416 == 400 c + 20 d + 420 a E^(Sqrt[13/17] b), 
   454 == 484 c + 22 d + 506 a E^(3 Sqrt[7/85] b)} /. b -> 0, {a, c, d}]
```

> `{}`